# Write modular UI Tests in XCode

Tags: swift, xcode, testing, xcode-ui-testing

I am pretty new to UI Testing on XCode. I found the record function pretty cool and it's working just fine but as long as you have decision points the code breaks the DRY principle. Therefore my idea is to write modular tests and invoke them depending of the user login status, role etc.

The problem is I don't find a way to tag my functions as not-tests (they are helpers invoked when appropriate from the main entry point). This is what I came up with

```
func testExample() {
   let exists = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")

   let app = XCUIApplication()

   if(!app.staticTexts[""].exists){
       testLaunchScreen()
   }
   testAsRole1()

}

func testLaunchScreen(){
    let app = XCUIApplication()

    let scrollViewsQuery = app.scrollViews
    scrollViewsQuery.otherElements.containing(.image, identifier:"image0").element.swipeLeft()
    app.buttons["Continue"].tap()
    testFacebookLoginScreen()
}


func testFacebookLoginScreen() {
    let app = XCUIApplication()

    // set up an expectation predicate to test whether elements exist
    let exists = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")
    // as soon as your sign in button shows up, press it
    let facebookSignInButton = app.buttons["Join with Facebook!"]
    expectation(for: exists, evaluatedWith: facebookSignInButton, handler: nil)
    facebookSignInButton.tap()


    self.waitForExpectations(timeout: 10, handler: nil)  
    if(app.staticTexts["Confirm"].exists){
        // create a reference to the button through the webView and press it
        let webView = app.descendants(matching: .webView)
        webView.buttons["OK"].tap()
    } else {
        let webViewsQuery = app.webViews
        webViewsQuery/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.textFields["Email or Phone"]/*[[".otherElements[\"Welcome to Facebook\"]",".otherElements[\"main\"].textFields[\"Email or Phone\"]",".textFields[\"Email or Phone\"]"],[[[-1,2],[-1,1],[-1,0,1]],[[-1,2],[-1,1]]],[0]]@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/.typeText("user@tfbnw.net")
        webViewsQuery/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.secureTextFields["Facebook Password"]/*[[".otherElements[\"Welcome to Facebook\"]",".otherElements[\"main\"].secureTextFields[\"Facebook Password\"]",".secureTextFields[\"Facebook Password\"]"],[[[-1,2],[-1,1],[-1,0,1]],[[-1,2],[-1,1]]],[0]]@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/.typeText("password")
        webViewsQuery.buttons["Login"].tap()   
    }
    // wait for your app to return and test for expected behavior here
    self.waitForExpectations(timeout: 10, handler: nil)  
}


func testAsRole1(){

  ///
}
```

The problem is that all the `testXXX` functions are run in order which is not what I want, I'd like to run just testExample. I have found some [post](http://averagepro.com/tag/xctest/) regarding extensions but I don't think those would fit in my case

Edited:
I have found https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF which seems a very nice library but I'd like to be able to just record sequences and name them as functions I can reuse, I think it would be easier to maintain

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

XCTest treats every method in an `XCTestCase` subclass that starts with `test` as a standalone test. Just change your  method names. Alternatively, you can put them in a separate class that doesn't inherit from `XCTestCase`, but then you lose the convenience methods defined there.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/xctest/xctestcase):

> Test methods are instance methods that have no parameters, do not return a value, and whose name begins with the lowercase word "test".

So, there are a couple of different ways you could modify those methods so that they're not treated as tests.

Comment: I was thinking about that `test` prefix convention but I thought: `nahh.. that would be documented mentioned somewhere` So +1 for you, -100 for Apple for not making it that more visible. If you could please link the docs I'd accept your reply :)